# Boot Kali with custom Filesystem

Tags: kali-linux, liveusb, squashfs

I'm trying to customize my "filesystem.squashfs" file, for my Kali live system. For modifying I used "unsquash" and for rebuilding "mksquash" without additional parameters. Now I replaced the old Filesystem with the new one. By booting the System stops by trying to mount (I think) the Filesystem.

What did I wrong? Hope for fast reply! Thanks in Advance!

Edit: 
I'm just trying to change Background Image, Keyboard Layout, install Squashfs-tools and Wine...

EditEdit: 
Looked at the Error Screen again, seem like the filesystem doesn't have the requested "/sbin/init". Then comes a "Bad File Descriptor" and "Kernel panic - not syncing: Attemped to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200" Would like to post a picture, but for any reason the app won't let me...

Comment: What's the error message you are getting, and what are you *actually* trying to achieve?